# Page is not working error for nginx - hostinger vps

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, vps

I purchased hostinger vps and i got a dedicated ip xx.xx.xx.113

nginx is properly installed and i could see it is active and running

to test the same; i tried to access http://xx.xx.xx.113/ which by default should show nginx index page.

http://xx.xx.xx.113/ this is not working; however https://xx.xx.xx.113:8443/login this is working (this is my cloud panel.io)

can someone help me why is this happening